# Question on geometry related to Trapezium and Isosceles Triangle

Tags: geometry

In figure $AD\perp DE$ and $BE\perp ED$.$C$ is mid point of $AB$.How to prove that $$CD=CE$$[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be on $DE$ such that $CH\perp DE$. You have that $C$ is midpoint of $AB$, and $CH||AD||BE\Rightarrow DH=EH$. Then $\triangle DHC\simeq\triangle EHC $ because $DH=EH$, $CH$ is common and $\angle DHC=\angle EHC=90^o$.

Comment: Please tell me about criterion for this congruence.

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: For showing $DH=EH$ we use Thales' itercept theorem

Comment: Can you please write the statement of Thales' intercept theorem.

Comment: See here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem
In particular we use the following consequence:  

If the midpoints of the two non-parallel sides of a trapezoid are connected, then the resulting line segment is parallel to the other two sides of the trapezoid.

Answer (score 2):

Draw $GH$ parallel to $DE$. GAC equals to the alternate one  CBH because cutting by parallels,GCA to its vertically opposite HCB, given $ CA= CB, $ so congruent.

[image: QnTrap]